# Can I update the source of Data found in a Data Lake or Data Blob

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

Is it possible to update the source of data found in a Data Lake or Data Blob? What about while using HDInsight or Azure Databricks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from my knowledge it is possible to update the data in a data lake or data blob, including when using HDInsight or Azure Databricks. These things are designed to be scalable, flexible, and easily updatable.

Mostly you will find these are done using batch processes that periodically update the data or using streaming data pipelines to continuously ingest new data in real-time.

Comment: Thank you @Vic I think that my question wasn't asked properly. What I meant is, is it possible to somehow update the source data itself, from which the data in the Data Lake originates from (understood that the data in the Data Lake itself can be updated).